# How to Organize Compose Imports by Moving Them to Another File and Importing in Another Screen?

Tags: android, optimization, android-jetpack-compose, code-cleanup

I'm working on an Android project using Jetpack Compose, and I have a screen with a long list of imports at the top. I want to clean up the code and make it more organized. Is there a way to move these imports into another file and then import that file into my Composable screen?

Here's a snippet of the imports I currently have at the top of my Composable file:

```
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.rememberLazyListState
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.rounded.Clear
import androidx.compose.material.icons.rounded.Search
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.LinearProgressIndicator
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.SideEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.derivedStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.google.accompanist.systemuicontroller.rememberSystemUiController
import com.insightlearning.heykt.R
import com.insightlearning.heykt.exten.collectAsLifecycleAwareState
import com.insightlearning.heykt.exten.colorSelection
import com.insightlearning.heykt.presentation.component.chip.ChipGroup
import com.insightlearning.heykt.presentation.component.question.QuestionLazyColumn
import com.insightlearning.heykt.presentation.component.textfield.TextFieldComponent
import com.insightlearning.heykt.presentation.component.textfield.TextFieldParams
import com.insightlearning.heykt.presentation.component.toolbar.AppToolbar
import com.insightlearning.heykt.presentation.component.toolbar.AppToolbarParams
import com.insightlearning.ui.theme.White
import com.insightlearning.ui.theme.largePadding
import kotlinx.collections.immutable.toPersistentList       
import androidx.compose.animation.EnterTransition
import androidx.compose.animation.ExitTransition
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Card
import androidx.compose.material3.CardDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
```

Comment: That's not how Kotlin (or Java) works. Just collapse the section in your IDE and ignore your imports.

Comment: Actually, I have a code analysis check that ensures files do not contain more than 60 lines. That's why I want to import more in other files and optimize them.

Comment: Why you assume 60 lines limit actually makes any sense to even bother?

Answer (score 1):

That isn't possible. Kotlin (and Java) require imports to be in the same file as where they are used. It is very common that you'll have many, many imports in a file. That's totally fine and expected.

If you have a 'code analysis check that ensures files do no contain more than 60 lines' you'll want to disable that for all Kotlin and Java files in your project.